# TG_TABLE_NAME with NEW in a trigger function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a shared trigger function used by multiple tables.

Each tables's primary key uses the format pk_ + tablename i.e. pk_account or pk_order

How can I dynamically reference the NEW object column in a trigger using a variable?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION shared_test_trigger_fn()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$$
DECLARE
  primary_key TEXT DEFAULT CONCAT('pk_', TG_TABLE_NAME);
  primary_value TEXT DEFAULT CONCAT('NEW.pk_', TG_TABLE_NAME);
BEGIN

    RAISE NOTICE 'The PK field is called %', primary_key;
    RAISE NOTICE 'The PK value is %', primary_value;
   
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS account_test_trigger ON account;
CREATE TRIGGER account_test_trigger BEFORE UPDATE
ON account
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE shared_test_trigger_fn();

UPDATE account SET created = created WHERE pk_account = 1;
```

EDIT1:
This trigger is simply an example to demonstrate the issue. The scenario is, we have a number of tables sharing a similar format with the PK field including the table name. Rather than code & maintain multiple similar trigger functions we are looking to have a single trigger function that can work with multiple tables.

Comment: Hi there. Could you elaborate on what the trigger is supposed to do and add the exact expected results?

Comment: The way to "dynamically reference" the column name depends on what you want to with it. Raising a notice with the name is different from executing SQL commands with it as identifier. Show a complete setup with the unsolved part as pseudo-code, please. And always disclose your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done fairly easy in [plpython3u](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpython.html):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.pk_tablename()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpython3u
AS $function$
pk = "pk_" + TD["table_name"]
pk_val = TD["new"][pk]
plpy.notice("PK value is " + str(pk_val))

$function$

CREATE TRIGGER trg_pk_tablename BEFORE UPDATE
ON animals
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE pk_tablename();

animals
                        Table "public.animals"
   Column   |          Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default 
------------+------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 pk_animals | integer                |           | not null | 
 cond       | character varying(200) |           | not null | 
 animal     | character varying(200) |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "animals_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (pk_animals)
Triggers:
    trg_pk_tablename BEFORE UPDATE ON animals FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION pk_tablename()

update animals set cond = 'good' where pk_animals = 200;
NOTICE:  PK value is 200
UPDATE 1
```

I have made attempts using `plpgsql` but have not found the magic sauce yet.